# gradle error in android build react native

Tags: android, gradle, react-native

[x] submitting bug

[x] Android platform react-native

[x] ubuntu 16.04 LTS

I am having issue in creating build by command **react-native run-android**

Here i am pasted error:

> $ react-native run-android Scanning folders for symlinks in
>   /home/pct3/webroot/Hello/node_modules (39ms) JS server already
>   running. Building and installing the app on the device (cd android &&
>   ./gradlew installDebug)...
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project 'Hello'.
>
>   > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
>   >     Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1.
>   >      Required by:
>   >          project :
>   >     Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1.
>   >     Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom'.
>   >     Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom'.
>   >     sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 12s Could not install the app on the device, read the
>   error above for details. Make sure you have an Android emulator
>   running or a device connected and have set up your Android development
>   environment:
>   https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Your help will save my day, if you need any extra information let me know.

Github link: [Issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17980)

Comment: "Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have set up your Android development environment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html" <-- did you do this?

Comment: a Gradle issue, you can delete Gradle build folder  android/.gradle and rebuild project.

Comment: @IshitaSinha yes i have setup Android development, i am using genemotion as emulator, adb devices command also display that emulator as running.

Comment: One thing i found weired that, app is runnig when run from android studio, but error of gradle when typing command `react-native run-android`

Comment: @AndroidTeam Tried but does not solving error

Answer (score 2):

a fast and easy solution to this issue is as following

1- open android/build.gradle
2-replace the gradle version with an older one for example 3.0.1

example of how it should look

```
classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1")
```

and boom no more issues

Answer (score 0):

Delete or rename the android folder and run react-native upgrade command.

Comment: That's a good solution, but it gives another error, error of gradle gone and new error is:

` > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not download protobuf-java.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.5.0)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/2.5.0/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/2.5.0/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar'.
            > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found `

Comment: Then the error belongs to your java gradle installation in your system.The error does not belongs to react native.Update or reinstall android sdk setup.

Answer (score 0):

Run `npm install`

Change your build.gradle so it follows this format:

*You can see all available artifacts at Google's Maven repository index (see below for programmatic access).
To add one of these libraries to your build, include Google's Maven repository in your top-level build.gradle file:*

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
      google()

    // If you're using a version of Gradle lower than 4.1, you must instead use:
    // maven {
    //     url 'https://maven.google.com'
    // }
    // An alternative URL is 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/'
 }
}
```

More info here https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies